# @detail_route does not work pagination in django rest framework

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

Can I use @detail_router's pagination?

```
class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    Group View Set
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

    @detail_route()
    def user(self, request, pk=None):
        _group = self.get_object()
        users_post = _group.user_set.all()
        page = self.paginate_queryset(users_post)
        if page is not None:
            serializers = UserSerializer(users_post, many=True, context={'request': request})
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializers.data)
        serializers = UserSerializer(users_post, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializers.data)
```

Pagination does not work well in Djagno Rest Framework.

[image]

It only works page size. One page has whole contents, and next page is same whole contents.
How can I do for pagination?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `users_post` in your `UserSerializer` you'll need to use `page`:

```
    if page is not None:
        serializers = UserSerializer(page, many=True, context={'request': request})
```

Edit:
Note that it should be `serializer` and not `serializers` as you only have one serializer.

Comment: Is this the best way to do this? Can't we do something like adding `pagination_class` to the `detail_route`

Comment: Not sure what you mean and this should be a different question.